# iOS: Getting the height of the tab.navigationBar in other controllers

Tags: ios, user-interface

How would you get access to `tab.navigationBar.height` in controllers other than MainViewController?

Answer (score 0):

If you have an application-wide references to your other controllers, this should be trivial. Although, if those controllers have not yet been displayed, it's possible that the height values will be invalid because viewDidAppear would not yet have been called. The position and dimension values of UIKit items cannot be relied upon until viewDidAppear has been called.